# Read json with JSONObject in angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

Following this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp i can parse a json perfectly but i've got a problem.. I have a php with a json in which inside there is a json something like this:

```
{"item":[ 
{
"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
"City" : "Berlin",
"Country" : "Germany"
},
{
"Name" : "Berglunds snabbköp",
"City" : "Luleå",
"Country" : "Sweden"
}]}
```

As you can see there is a JSONObject (item).. actually to parse a json without JSONObject i do this function inside my controller:

```
$http.get(JSONUrl)
        .success(function(response) {
            $scope.names = response;
        });
```

and then

```
<div data-ng-controller="MainController">
                <table class="uk-table uk-table-striped uk-table-hover" data-ng-if="!loading && !error">
                    <thead>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>Ver</th>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr data-ng-repeat="item in names">
                        <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.City}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.Country}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

But in my case i display nothing becase i have that "item" as JSONObject.. Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is you are not using correct property in response JSON Object

*Use*

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="item in names.item">
```

*instead of*

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="item in names">
```

**OR**

```
$scope.names = response.item;
```

Comment: Amazing it works!! there is no documentation about that right? Thank you

Comment: Sure, the documentation for using ng-repeat should cover it. To be clear, the only change he made was he referenced the property that was an array, rather than the object as a whole. You won't find documentation that explains that, that's javascript 101. If you want to repeat on name.item, use name.item.

Comment: Oh thanks, i'm a little bit rusty with javascript :)